# Open but not restart app via a Custom URL scheme on Android

Tags: android, url

I register an url scheme for my android app and configure file as following shows, however, it will restart the app every time by this way. How could I only make it just open app , not restart it? Thanks.

```
<intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="myapp"/>

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
 </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to set `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` parameter for an Activity you are calling.

Comment: I can't understand what you are talking about. Maybe "intent" instead of "internet"?

Comment: Thanks ! the problem is resolved.  I found the problem is not restarting app  but starting a new app by browser. Thanks for your help!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324766/app-started-from-deep-link-then-activated-again-from-launcher-restarts-the-acti/75811046#75811046