# App started from deep link, then activated again from launcher restarts the activity

Tags: android, android-activity, deep-linking

The following situation:

- app is started from a deep link (sms) and launches the MainActivity
- user presses the start button in the app which opens SecondActivity
- app goes into background
- user presses on app icon again in launcher => HERE I EXPECT the SecondActivity be still active. But instead, MainActivity is relaunched.

Tried with "singleTop" activity mode - no difference.

SecondActivity is launched from MainActivity without any special intent flags, plain startActivity()

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE”/>
```

Comment: Can I see your `manifest` file?

Comment: Updated with manifest piece

Comment: Can you try with `lauchmode="singleTask"`? I don't know it will solve. One thing I want to say normally we are not starting the launcher activity   using `startActivity()`.

Comment: How is the deep link launched?

Comment: You could be seeing a nasty Android bug. What happens after you launch the app from HOME screen and press BACK key? Do you now see `SecondActivity`? or does the app just exit?

Comment: Can you override the onPause and onDestroy lifecycle events in both activities and log a message out when they are called, if the onDestroy is being called then your app isnt going into the background, its being killed which would explain why its restarting  the app.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out there are two reasons:

1. Starting app from deep link created separate instance of the app => solved by specifying "singleTask"
2. The SecondActivity was destroyed at some point, which explains why starting the app again from icon will bring MainActivity screen

Thanks all commenters for helpful hints!

Comment: Well I have to get back my words on point 2: I do not destroy the SecondActivity, it's being destroyed by operating system and I still do not get why

Answer (score 0):

When starting the secondActivity you can just call `finish()` in the firstActivity (for example in `onPause()` or `buttonClick()` firstActivity). In this way, your app is still running (i.e secondActivity). When you launch the app the secondActivity should run directly (if the app is not totally destroyed yet).

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` as recommended in answers/comments but rather use `android:launchMode="singleTop"` because with singleTask custom tab will be opened as separate app (in opened apps list will be both chrome with custom tab and your real app) and user can switch between chrome app with your custom tab and your real app (it can be misleading to user) which can lead to undesirable situations:

- user can kill your real app, but chrome with custom will be still in opened apps list,
- user can open as many chrome instances in app list with your custom tab when he always switches from custom tab back to app and open another chrome custom tab in opened apps list,
- and maybe many other combinations

Comment: UPDATE: I do not know what changed but now with `singleTask` it does not open custom tabs separately app in opened app list. I have must switched back from `singleTop` to `singleTask` due to Firefox on Android because app activity was restarted when user Firefox browser for custom tabs. Chrome's custom tabs do not restart activity with any `singleTask` or `singleTop`.